# REACT local mp3 is not playing on website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise, html5-audio

I am creating a podcast SPA. I store all the data of each podcast in a json.file, that I am rendering dynamically throughout my components.
In the json, I store in a key the path to the mp3 file, which are saved in a podcast folder inside the public folder.

I am expecting to play the file once I am inside the info component, which include the audio player, and then let the audio player keep on playing when navigating in the website. Instead the file seems not to be read at all (duration of the track is also not shown and it appear as NaN).

Once I click on play in the console appear the message: "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources."
As I understand play() return a promise, but I don't seem to understand how to integrate it in the code, as for my understanding, I am not waiting for a response since my file are uploaded locally.

This is my structure:

- public

  - images
  - podcast
- src

  - components

    - Home.js
    - Navbar.js
    - Tiles.js
    - Info.js
    - AudioPlayer.js
    - Footer.js
  - data

    - data.json

This is what i have:

DATA.JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": "001",
    "title": "BOB",
    "cover": "/images/bob.png",
    "info": "Released 1978",
    "file_podcast": "/podcast/TRACK#1.mp3"
  },
  {
    "id": "002",
    "title": "PAUL",
    "cover": "/images/paul.png",
    "info": "Released 1983",
    "file_podcast": "/podcast/TRACK#2.mp3"
  },
```

HOME.JS

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Info from "./Info";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Tiles from "./Tiles";
import data from "../data/data";

const Home = () => {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="m-5">
      <Navbar />
      {info ? (
        <Info info={info} backToTiles={() => setInfo(null)} />
      ) : (
        <Tiles data={data} setInfo={setInfo} />
      )}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

TILES.JS

```
import React from "react";

const Tiles = ({ data, setInfo }) => {

  return (
    <>
    
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-3 mt-5">
        {data &&
          data
            .slice(0)
            .reverse()
            .map((item) => {
              return (
                <div key={item.id} onClick={() => setInfo(item)}>
                  <img
                    alt={item.title}
                    src={`${item.cover}`}
                    className="h-50 w-35 hover:opacity-25"
                    title={item.title}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Tiles;
```

INFO.JS

```
import React from "react";
import { AiOutlineArrowLeft, AiOutlinePlayCircle } from "react-icons/ai";
import AudioPlayer from "./AudioPlayer";

const Info = ({ info, backToTiles }) => {
  console.log(info.file_podcast);

  return (
    <div key={info.id} className="mt-5">
      <div className="relative">
        <AiOutlineArrowLeft
          className="absolute top-0 right-10 h-16 w-16 text-white cursor-pointer"
          onClick={backToTiles}
        />
      </div>
      <img src={info.cover} alt="Cover"  className="ml-10" />
      <div className="flex ml-10 mt-5 justify-start items-center">
        <AiOutlinePlayCircle className="h-16 w-16 text-white" />
        <p className="text-3xl font-bold ml-3">{info.title}</p>
      </div>
      <p className="w-6/12 ml-10 mt-5">{info.info}</p>
      <AudioPlayer file={info.file_podcast}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Info;
```

AUDIOPLAYER.JS

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  AiFillBackward,
  AiFillForward,
  AiFillFastBackward,
  AiFillFastForward,
  AiOutlinePlayCircle,
  AiOutlinePause,
} from "react-icons/ai";

const AudioPlayer = ({ file }) => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
  const [audio] = useState(new Audio(file));

  // ref to audio element
  const audioPlayer = useRef();

  // ref to progress bar
  const progressBar = useRef();

  // ref to animation progress bar
  const animationRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const seconds = Math.floor(audioPlayer.current.duration);
    setDuration(seconds);
    progressBar.current.max = seconds;
  }, [audioPlayer?.current?.loadedmetadata, audioPlayer?.current?.readyState]);

  const calculateTime = (time) => {
    const hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
    const returnedHours = hours < 10 ? `0${hours}` : `${hours}`;
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    const returnedMinutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : `${minutes}`;
    const seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);
    const returnedSeconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : `${seconds}`;
    return `${returnedHours}:${returnedMinutes}:${returnedSeconds}`;
  };

  const togglePlayPause = () => {
    const prevValue = isPlaying;
    setIsPlaying(!prevValue);
    if (!prevValue) {
      audioPlayer.current.play();
      animationRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(whilePlaying);
    } else {
      audioPlayer.current.pause();
      cancelAnimationFrame(animationRef.current);
    }
    console.log(file);
  };

  const whilePlaying = () => {
    progressBar.current.value = audioPlayer.current.currentTime;
    setCurrentTime(audioPlayer.current.value);
    animationRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(whilePlaying);
  };

  const changeRange = () => {
    audioPlayer.current.currentTime = progressBar.current.value;
    setCurrentTime(progressBar.current.value);
  };

  const backThirty = () => {
    progressBar.current.value = Number(progressBar.current.value) - 30;
    changeRange();
  };

  const forwardThirty = () => {
    progressBar.current.value = Number(progressBar.current.value) + 30;
    changeRange();
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center m-10">
      <audio ref={audioPlayer} src={audio} preload="metadeta" />
      <button className="player_buttons">
        <AiFillBackward className="player_icons" />
      </button>
      <button className="player_buttons" onClick={backThirty}>
        <AiFillFastBackward className="player_icons" />
      </button>
      <button className="player_buttons" onClick={togglePlayPause}>
        {isPlaying ? (
          <AiOutlinePause className="player_icons" />
        ) : (
          <AiOutlinePlayCircle className="player_icons" />
        )}
      </button>
      <button className="player_buttons" onClick={forwardThirty}>
        <AiFillFastForward className="player_icons" />
      </button>
      <button className="player_buttons">
        <AiFillForward className="player_icons" />
      </button>

      {/* current time */}
      <div>{calculateTime(currentTime)}</div>

      {/* progress bar */}
      <div>
        <input
          type="range"
          className="progressBar w-100"
          defaultValue="0"
          ref={progressBar}
          onChange={changeRange}
        />
      </div>

      {/* duration */}
      <div>{duration && !isNaN(duration) && calculateTime(duration)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AudioPlayer;
```

Comment: Please post the full error stack for "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException..." and what line of your code it's related to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries, I found out that it's not considerate a good practice to use special character in a json file. My podcast name was listed as #001, #002, #003 and so on. After I removed the # from the file name, the AudioPlayer component start to read the file and be able to play them.